# ycm_client_support.[so|pyd|dll] and ycm_core.[so|pyd|dll] not detected; you need to compile YCM before using it

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

orror in compile prses. how to solve it?

Comment: YCM issue tracker is [this way](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [this](https://susu.github.io/posts/clang-completion-in-vim-with-youcompleteme/) blog post, you just have to compile the YouCompleteMe modules by running the `install.sh` script in the YCM install.

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe
./install.sh --clang-completer
```

Once this completes you should be able to install the plugin (here's how to do it with [Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim)). Once in Vim

```
:source ~/.vimrc
:PluginInstall
```

Comment: As of 3/16 states that the install.sh is dep, and you should use the .py script

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, when you run `./.install.sh --clang-completer` it says that it is "out of date."

I ran `python2 install.py` and it worked for me. (I believe it was python2.)

Also, I had was using vim and neovim, and I decided to do `./install.sh --clang-completer` inside my `~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim/` and **at the same tim** decided to do `python2 install.py` inside my `~/.configs/nvim/bundle/Vundle.vim/` and the *python* install installed faster and did the same thing.

The difference *might* be that you need to "compile vim with pdython support," but the simple fix for that is installing `python-nvim` (if using neovim), or - I think - vim just comes with python support. (? maybe.)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error message when trying out new neovim installation. In my case, it was because I was using vim-plugin and the plugins are installed in the `~/.vim/plugged` instead of `~/.vim/bundle` (this is the plugin folder for Vundle before I switched to vim-plug).

Thus, after scratching my head for few hours, turns out I have to run `install.sh` in the `~/.vim/plugged` (not `~/.vim/bundle`). I hope this will save someone's time.